# How to wait in loop in Vaadin?

Tags: java, image, time, vaadin, sleep

Im trying to display series of photos on one page with time interval. In countinuos while loop i got:

```
while(true){

        if (zmienna == fa.length) zmienna = 0; 
        Image obrazek = new Image("",pliki[zmienna]);

        layout.replaceComponent(staryObrazek, obrazek);
        obrazek.requestRepaint();
        staryObrazek = obrazek;
        zmienna++;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000) ;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        }
```

It showing only waiting icon, dispaying mwthod works fine without loop. Do anyone has an idea how I should fic this issue?

Answer (score 2):

In all modern UI systems you will have to not suspend the main thread, but use a background thread to update the UI. Otherwise you block the whole UI.

In Vaadin 7 you can enable server push and then use a background thread to change the image every 2 seconds.

Enabling push is described in the book of vaadin https://vaadin.com/de/book/vaadin7/-/page/advanced.push.html

Your code could look like this:

```
public class PushyUI extends UI {

@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
    // Set first component/image
    setContent(chart);

    // Start the update thread
    new ImgUpdThread().start();
}

class ImgUpdThread extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {    
            // Update the data for a while
            while (count < 100) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);

                access(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //update the UI as in your code above
                    }
                });
            }
   }
```

It is important to use the access(...) method to sync access to the UI elements.

Comment: For me, the UI changes made are not seen until the user does something else to force a refresh (e.g clicks a button). Any ideas?

Comment: @AndyW Have you enabled any of the server push methods?

Comment: No I hadn't. Just added "@Push" above my MainView class and it now works!

Comment: You can use `getUI().setPollInterval()` instead.